# Feeds creates duplicate content each time cron runs

Tags: 7, feeds

I have created a custom feed importer but each time it runs it creates the same content again. How can I make it only create the content once?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to update existing nodes, Feeds needs a unique ID to match the source item with the target node. Otherwise, Feeds cannot know which node to update, so it just creates a new one.

When configuring the mapping for your feed importer, choose a unique field in the source, map it to the 'GUID' target and check the 'unique target' checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Unique field](https://www.drupal.org/project/unique_field) module to assure that nodes with fields you specify as unique cannot be saved twice. Here is an excerpt about it from the module's project page:

> ... performs additional validation when a node is created or updated by a user to require that a node's title, author, language, and CCK fields are unique within a given context.
>
> Without this module, Drupal and CCK do not prevent multiple nodes from having the same title or the same value in a certain field.
>
> For example, if you have a content type with a date field and there should only be one node per date, you could use this module to prevent a node from being saved with a date already used in another node.

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting under *admin/structure/feeds/{importer name}* >> Basic settings >> settings >> **Periodic import** , you have to turn this off in order to avoid recreation of previously imported content.